# React:Not able to access the component form data into another component

Tags: reactjs

I have two components one is Home component and Category component. First its redirecting to Home page use of routing.
In home page ,I have two fields, username and password. I filled the username and password and click on submit, its redirecting to category page.
I want access the username and password fields in category component.
I am not able to access those fields in category component.

```
render() {
return (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar navbar-default">
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="navbar-header">
            <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
          </div>
          <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
              <Link className="active" to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/category">Category</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>

      <hr />
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/category" component={Category} />
    </div>
  </Router>

)

 render() {
return (
  <form >
    <label>
      Name:
      <input type="text" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange = {(event) => this.setState({username:event.target.value})}/>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <label>
      password:
      <input type="text" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange = {(event) => this.setState({password:event.target.value})}/>
    </label>
    <br/>
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)} value="Submit" />
  </form>
);
}  
}

constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            console.log("props", this.props);

            console.log("props....", props)
    }
    clickForSettings() {
            this.props.history.push('/settings');
    }

    render() {
            return (
                    <div>
                    <h1>This is Category Page{this.props.username}</h1>

                    </div>

            );
    }
```

Comment: How are you passing the property `username` to `Category` page?

Comment: I had  set  the username in state. State  is accessible for  inside  the  component. But how  to get  the username value?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Read up on [this article on data storage in react](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/where-do-i-belong-a-guide-to-saving-react-component-data-in-state-store-static-and-this-c49b335e2a00), and if you decide you still want to do it the way you're operating, you'll want to do the below:

First, put the variables you want in the lowest common "parent" of the two classes you want to share data. For you, this sounds like the class where you have your router.

Second, create a function that alters the variables, just like you would've in your home controller. For you, this would probably be these two functions:

```
changeUserName(userName){ this.setState({ userName: userName }) }
changePassword(password){ this.setState({ password: password }) }
```

Third, [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) those functions to the "parent" component, so that `this` is always pointing to the parent's `this` (this must be done in the constructor of the "parent"):

```
this.changeUserName = this.changeUserName.bind(this);
this.changePassword = this.changePassword.bind(this);
```

Fourth, send the functions down into `Home`, and the variables down into `Category` using timdorr's solution [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/5521).

Fifth, call the method in the input onChange functions in the Home class:

```
onChange(event) { this.props.changeUserName(event.target.value) }
```

Now you should be able to see the changes on your `Category` component with `this.props.userName` or however you sent it down to your `Category` component.

---

**Sample of the method outlined above**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      userName:""
    }
    this.changeUserName = this.changeUserName.bind(this);
  }
  changeUserName(userName) {
    this.setState({userName});
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Login userName={this.state.userName} changeUserName={this.changeUserName} />
        <NeedsUserName userName={this.state.userName} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default class Login extends Component {
  changeUserName(event) {
    this.props.changeUserName(event.target.value);
  }
  render() {
    <input onChange={(event) => this.changeUserName(event)} value={this.props.userName}/>
  }
}

export default class NeedsUserName extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <h1>{this.props.userName}</h1>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: If this is by design,.is there any alternation solution other than this.

Comment: @RamakrishnaReddy a sample has been provided, and you can find alternate solutions at the link I provided